# Parsing page source using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, domdocument, text-parsing

I'm having a lot of trouble parsing the page source of a results page. The results page returns data about businesses in a city. This data includes name, address, phone number, owner name and URL. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is an example of one of the results (There are hundreds in the original file):

```
<div class="ListingResults_All_CONTAINER ListingResults_Level3_CONTAINER">
  <div class="ListingResults_Level3_HEADER">
    <div class="ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLERIGHT">
      <div><a href="/Restaurants/317-at-Montgomery-7897"><img src="/external/wcpages/images/L3more.gif" alt="317 at Montgomery"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFT">
      <div class="ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFTBOX"><strong><span itemprop="name"><a href="/Restaurants/317-at-Montgomery-7897">317 at Montgomery</a></span></strong></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAIN">
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAINRIGHT">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAINRIGHTBOX">
        <div class="ListingResults_Level3_LOGO"><a href="/Restaurants/317-at-Montgomery-7897" class="ListingResults_Level3_LOGO"><img src="http://www.centerstateceo.com/external/wcpages/wcwebcontent/webcontentpage.aspx?contentid=2071" class="ListingResults_Level3_LOGOIMG"></a><div style="width:100%;height:1px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ListingResults_MAINRIGHTBOXDIVIDER" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:1px;">_</div>
        <div class="ListingResults_Level3_AFFILIATIONS"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAINLEFT">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAINLEFTBOX" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address" itemscope="" itemprop="address"><span itemprop="street-address">317 Montgomery St.</span><br><span itemprop="locality">Syracuse</span>, <span itemprop="region">NY</span>  <span itemprop="postal-code">13202  </span><div class="ListingResults_Level3_MAINCONTACT"><a href="/directory/directoryemailform.aspx?listingid=7897"><img src="/external/wcpages/images/maincontact.gif" alt="Mr. Dean Whittles">Mr. Dean Whittles</a></div>
        <div class="ListingResults_Level3_PHONE1"><img src="/external/wcpages/images/phone.gif" alt="Work Phone: (315) 214-4267">(315) 214-4267</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTER">
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_DESCRIPTION">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_DESCRIPTIONBOX"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERRIGHT">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERRIGHTBOX">
        <div class="ListingResults_Level3_SOCIALMEDIA"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERRIGHT">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERRIGHTBOX">
        <div class="ListingResults_Level3_COUPONS"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERLEFT">
      <div class="ListingResults_Level3_FOOTERLEFTBOX"><span class="ListingResults_Level3_LEARNMORE"><a href="/Restaurants/317-at-Montgomery-7897" class="level3_footer_left_box_a friendly">
                    Learn More
                  </a></span><span class="ListingResults_Level3_VISITSITE"> | <a href="http://www.317syr.com" onclick="recordReferralOnClick('20947', '7897', 'W');" target="_blank">
                    Visit Site
                  </a></span><span class="ListingResults_Level3_MAP"> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addItemToMapWithArrayIndexOf('0');recordReferralOnClick('20947', '7897', 'M');" class="level3_footer_left_box_a">Show on Map</a></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code from Comment:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($data);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($spans as $el) {
    $children = $el->childNodes->item(1);
    if (is_object($children) AND $children->tagName == 'a') {
        $url = $children->getAttribute('href');
        echo $url;
        continue;
    }
    $user_param = $el->getAttribute('itemprop');
    $value      = $el->nodeValue;
    if ($user_param != "") {
        echo $user_param . " " . $value . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the code you are trying to use to parse the data?

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($data);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

foreach($spans as $el) {
 $children = $el->childNodes->item(1);
 if(is_object($children) AND $children->tagName == 'a')
 {
  $url = $children->getAttribute('href');
  echo $url;
  continue;
 }
  
   $user_param = $el->getAttribute('itemprop');
   $value = $el->nodeValue;
   if($user_param != "")
   {
    echo $user_param." ".$value."\n";
   }
}

Comment: Post your code by editing your question - code in comments really doesn't work well. While I'm here, you should probably look at using XPath to extract what you want from this data.

Comment: it is too difficult to read long code in comment. I have copied it to question this time, please do it yourself next time.

Comment: Use [a microdata parser](https://github.com/linclark/MicrodataPHP).